# "Create a legacy form" missing from Google Docs spreadsheet?

Tags: android, google-docs, acra

Is the Tools->"Create a legacy form" option missing from anybody else's Google Docs spreadsheet? I've used this up until now for several apps using ACRA. I went to create a new spreadsheet for a new app, imported the template but the option is no longer showing under my Tools menu. If this has finally been deprecated then it may render ACRA useless for new projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google indicated about 9 months ago that this usage was deprecated and that was echoed in the ACRA doco. You just need to use another backend. Keven has created ACRAlyzer and there are options like BugSense that offer free and paid tiers.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I guessed Google had finally got rid of it, I just couldn't find anything official.